# How to get the random pod number provided by Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, minikube

I would like to get and see the random number provided by K8s.

```
kubectl logs abc-abc-platform-xxxxx dicom-server
```

Here xxxxx has to be replaced with the random generated number.

Can you let me know which command do I have to execute to find the random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the specific pod has the `my-app` label, you can find that pod and save it as bash variable:

- `POD=$(kubectl get pod -l app=my-app -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")`

and then execute:

- `kubectl logs $POD`

*PS. This will work only if you have 1 pod with that specific label.*

Comment: @AVLES was it helpful?